# Blacklist and preg_match

Tags: php

I thought I had this figured out, but I'm running into an issue. I'm creating a URL blacklist in my application. I need to block all subdomains, directories, etc from an array of domains. Below is the array I have:

```
$blacklist = array(
'/\.google\./',
'/\.microsoft\./',
);
```

Here is where I'm checking:

```
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $blackList = $GLOBALS['blacklist'];
    foreach($blackList as $stop) {
        if (preg_match($host === $stop)) {
            die('blacklisted');
            }
        }
```

When I run this, it doesn't die as intended.

Comment: **There may be an appropriate time to use `$GLOBALS`, but I haven't encountered it yet**. For more see [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreach loop should be like this:

```
foreach($blacklist as $stop) {
        if (preg_match($stop, $host)) {
            die("blacklisted\n");
        }
}
```

You had 2 problems:

1. array variable was named as `blacklist` but you were using `blackList` in `foreach` loop.
2. `preg_match` was being used incorrectly, it needs at least 2 arguments like in my answer.

Comment: See it working here: http://ideone.com/fdmTo and print your variable `$url` using `var_dump($url);` to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Everything you posted looks good. I did a `print_r($blackList)` and it returned an empty array. I guess that's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) wrong!

```
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

foreach ($blacklist as $pattern){
  $matches = array();
  preg_match($pattern, $host, $matches);
  if (count($matches)) die('blacklisted');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without foreach:

```
if(preg_match('/'.implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $blacklist)).'/i', $string))
{
   die("blacklisted");
}
```